# Reverse ip lookup

Tags: ssh, networking

I was wondering if it is somehow possible to lookup the ip of a machine I ssh'd into from. This is the scenario, I'm at home, I've VPN'd into a server that I ssh into constantly in the office but now I want to ssh into the machine that I use locally.

If that doesn't make sense hopefully this will. In the office I use my desktop a *nix box to ssh into a server. Now that I'm at home I want to ssh into that *nix box through the server but I don't know the IP of that local box, is there a log somewhere that might keep track of that sort of information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use the last command to figure out all the connections and where from. append the `-a` flag so the host/ip doesn't get cut off.

```
last -a
```

Comment: Don't thank, upvote and/or accept.